# What is a fund?

Tags: meaning

Google definition defines *fund* as

> A sum of money saved or made available for a particular purpose.

However, while I was looking up the definition of a trust fund, Google definition states it is,

> A fund consisting of assets belonging to a trust, held by the trustees for the beneficiaries.

So is a *fund* merely a sum of money, or can also be assets/properties?

Comment: I think this is General Reference. OED *4 sing. A **stock** or sum of money, esp. one set apart for a particular purpose.* Just because *funds* are usually "money-based", and that's the only definition given by Google, doesn't make this a useful question. At [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fund) there's *supply; stock: a fund of knowledge; a fund of jewels.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Whoa there, Scrooge! Per [Marthaª’s ***featured*** meta request](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/3449/2085), we non-♦-mods are trying to withhold our close votes and down votes during these Twelve Days of Christmas. The mods are doing a good job at closing true dupes and truly unsalvageable genrefs by themselves. Still use flags as needed of course, and certainly delete-vote You Know Whose Postings, but otherwise try to work to salvage a post if you can, or keep mum otherwise. Hippocrates says first do no harm. Remember: ***Marthaª knows if you’ve been bad or good....***

Comment: @tchrist: I was good as gold throughout 2011, but Martha never gave me a present last xmas. And Kitfox cruelly misled me about my [chance of getting shagged by good-looking and/or famous people](http://english.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-75664) in the elections. Women? I don't trust 'em! :)

Comment: @Fumble Now see here. I only *suggested* that it might help. I did not make any promises.

Comment: @KitFox: Just kidding! (but I *am* still "on a promise" for the ELU New Year's Eve party, right? :)

Comment: Don't the 12 days start on the 25th? @tchrist?

Comment: @MattЭллен  Perhaps ELU is still on the Julian calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, a fund consists of assets that can be directly expressed in some currency—money, I would say—, although its meaning is usually not defined very strictly. So a bank account or a deposit would count. However, the word is very often used more loosely, so don't be surprised to find a fund containing stocks and bonds as well. And a trust fund can be even broader, including any kind of investment that can be sold within a reasonable or expected time, I would say.